# Grouped TableView separator line

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a grouped tableView with 3 sections. On the last section I have a single cell with a label. I need it to be completely transparent. I've done that but I still have the separator lines around and it's not very UI-pretty.

Is there any way to remove the separator lines for just one cell (or section for that matter)

Thanks in advance!